# get method parameters on prepareForSegue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a method that gets the data(specifiers and title) from that row and i after segue.

```
- (void)yd_deleteViewControllerWithTargetTypeSpecifiable:(id<YDTargetTypeSpecifiable>)specifier
                                                                     title:(NSString *)title
                                                                   onClose:(void(^)(void))onCloseBlock
{
    NSLog(@"%@/%@", title, specifier.target_id);
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEUGE_GO_DELETE sender:self];
}
```

How can i pass that parameter from prepareForSegue?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:SEUGE_GO_DELETE]) {

        // Get destination view
        YDDeleteViewController *makeDC = (YDDeleteViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        // Pass the information to your destination view
        makeDC.labelname = @"title";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put parameters in `sender`

Answer (score 1):

Store the info you need in ivars (properties):

```
NSLog(@"%@/%@", title, specifier.target_id);
[self setTitleInfo:title];
[self setSpecifierInfo:specifier];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEUGE_GO_DELETE sender:self];
```

Then in `prepareForSegue` you pick them up:

```
YDDeleteViewController *makeDC = (YDDeleteViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
// pick up [self titleInfo] and pass it along to makeDC
// pick up [self specifierInfo] and pass it along to makeDC
```

Comment: when i declare `[self setTitleInfo:title];` this error comes No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'setTitleInfo:'

Comment: You have to create those properties. That’s what I’m saying. You need to set yourself up with a way to pass the info around by using ivars as a drop.

Comment: Can you be more specific, i am new in xcode and not really know where to declare the ivar. thanks a lot for your time

Comment: I’ve written a book that teaches you. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch05.html#_instance_variables_and_accessors